# estoy haciendo responsive y me aparece un scroll con un borde blanco

Tags: html, css, responsive

```css
html,
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
}

.menu {
    background-color:#3457f7;
    padding-left:0px;   
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;        
display: inline-block;
}

.buscador {

   text-align: right;
    position:relative;
    /*top/bottom/
    left/right*/
    top:0;
    Left:0;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: -70px; left: -20px;
}


.logo {
 height: 17%;
 width: 17%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  position: relative;
top: -90px; left: 0px;

}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
/*top/bottom/
left/right*/
top: 50px; left: 130px;
width: 80%;
}
.local{
   border-color: red;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
}
ul{
   border-color: green;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
}



footer{
    border-color: #FF00CD;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
}

.tela{
 height: 40%;
 width: 40%;
}
.tela2{
  height: 40%;
 width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
    
<html lang="es">    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Telas</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="imagen/x-icon" href="imagen/descarga.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prog/prog.css">    
</head>
<body>
<header class="menu">   
    <h1>Telas x Mayor</h1>
        
    <form>
        <div class="buscador">
         Buscador x Tela: 
        <input type="text"placeholder="Buscar nombre de la Tela">
        <input type="button"value="Buscar">
        </div>
        
        <div >
            <img class="logo" src="imagen/logo.jpg" alt="telas" title="telas varias"/> 
        </div>
    
    </header>
    </form>
        
        <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
    
        
        <a href="productos.html">Productos</a>
    
    
        <a href="quienes-somos.html">Quienes Somos</a>
  
    
        <a href="preguntas-frecuentes.html">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
    

        <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
        

            <div> 
                <img class="tela" width="100%" src="imagen/images.jpg" alt="Telas" title="Telas Variadas"> 
                <img class="tela2" width="100%" src="imagen/images2.jpg" alt="Telas" title="Telas Variadas"> 
            </div>
        
        <ul class="pago">  
          <li> Tarjeta de Credito  </li>
          <li> Mercado Pago </li>
          <li> Transferencia / Efectivo </li>
          <li> Envios a todo el Pais </li> 
        </ul>    
            <div class="local">
             <p>Corrientes 2800</p>
             <p>CABA</p>    
            </div>
        <footer>
         <p>Tel 45555555 </p>
         <p>WSP 55555555 </p>
         <p>Mail telas@gmail.com </p>
        </footer>  
      
      
    
</body>
</html>     

por fa ayuda no puedo sacar el scrool en responsive y me queda un borde blanco,probe sacarlo y no puedo estoy volvinedome loco y ya no se que hacer, las imagenes son 3 una es el logo, y las otras dos son imagenes de tela que estan en google. espero alguien me ayude, gracias.
el borde me aparece solo a la izquierda y no es muy grande pero me hace scroll es bastante odioso si hay algo que no se entiende escribanlo y lo contesto o corrigo. espero su colaboracion hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  hhhhhhhh hhhhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhh  hhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhh hhhhhhhhhhhhh
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega una descripción del problema que surge. No se aprecia donde parece el borde blanco. Escribe el problema con detalles fuera del código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres quitar el scroll que mencionas, puedes aplicar la siguiente propiedad a las etiquetas `html, body`:

```
html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* <- ocultamos el scroll horizontal */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* <- ocultamos el scroll vertical */
}
```

saludos.

Comment: Gracias kpo me salvaste